# How can I post a mp4 using moviepy without saving it in local storage?

Tags: django, python-3.x, file, moviepy

I'm trying to make a server that concatenate two videos in one. But i need a server which don't save the temp file in my local folder or any folder, only using the memory.

```py
clip1 = VideoFileClip(videoBegin)
clip2 = VideoFileClip(videoEnd)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1, clip2])

# final_clip.write_videofile('video.mp4')

files = {'file': final_clip}

hea = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + token}

import requests

res = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=hea)
```

But the problem is the request can't send the `moviepy` object, because it needs a `bytes-like`. `*** TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'VideoClip'`. Is there a way to send a video from `moviepy` without saving in folder? And only use the memory?

I'm using Django as a server. I don't know if it helps.

Comment: try `files = {'file': open(final_clip, 'rb')}` instead of `files = {'file': final_clip}`.

Comment: The reason that this isn't possible is that all edits and transformations to a clip are only actually applied when you write the clip to a file. That is why concatenating or applying transformations to a clip happens near-instantly, because the computations are performed during the write_videofile render.